# Color under a point or from a SHAPE

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am using flash as3.

I have some shapes I have drawn on the screen.  They are made using:

```
graphics.beginFill(0x00ff00);
graphics.drawRect(0,0,50,50);
graphics.endFill();
```

to draw them.  Each shape has a different color for fun (different beginFill).

How can I get the color of the shape under the mouse pointer as I move the mouse around the shapes?

I see two choices so far but don't know how to do either of them:
Get color under the mouse point
get the color from the shape properties (preferred)

I have no idea how to do either of these...Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

s1 = instancename of the movieclip holding your first shape
s2 = instancename of the movieclip holding your second shape
s3 = instancename of the movieclip holding your third shape

(must be different movieclips)

and so on...

So you'll need to change those values.

If you need any explanation just drop a comment and i'll help you

otherwise you can simply copy/paste this code:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.display.BitmapData;
```

var myColor:String;

s1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, storeColor1);
s2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, storeColor2);
s3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, storeColor3);

function storeColor1(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    var BmD:BitmapData = new BitmapData(s1.width, s1.height);
    var Bm:Bitmap = new Bitmap(BmD);
    BmD.draw(s1);
    s1.addChild(Bm);
    myColor = BmD.getPixel(s1.mouseX,s1.mouseY).toString(16);

```
while(myColor.length < 6)
{
    myColor = "0" + myColor;
}

trace(myColor);}
```

function storeColor2(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    var BmD:BitmapData = new BitmapData(s2.width, s2.height);
    var Bm:Bitmap = new Bitmap(BmD);
    BmD.draw(s2);
    s2.addChild(Bm);
    myColor = BmD.getPixel(s2.mouseX,s2.mouseY).toString(16);

```
while(myColor.length < 6)
{
    myColor = "0" + myColor;
}

trace(myColor);}
```

function storeColor3(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    var BmD:BitmapData = new BitmapData(s3.width, s3.height);
    var Bm:Bitmap = new Bitmap(BmD);
    BmD.draw(s3);
    s3.addChild(Bm);
    myColor = BmD.getPixel(s3.mouseX,s3.mouseY).toString(16);

`while(myColor.length < 6)
{
    myColor = "0" + myColor;
}

trace(myColor);}`

Btw, this is just some code i wrote in 5 minutes to give you an idea of how it works. This is not an optimized code at all.

Comment: For anyone reading this, it is more complex than required for the problem but you can figure out the solution from the bitmap data part.  Thanks Zrean

Comment: A simple question gets a simple answer. If you had posted a more complex code i would have adapted the answer to that code. But the current code works for the question posted above.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to go is probably to create your own class, so you can keep your color (even random) in a variable, and handle different mouse events (use of graphics need an extends from MovieClip anyway) inside of the same class, or instead of handling the mouse itslef, dispatch your own event when mouse is over your sprite.

Another way is to draw your rects into a bitmap object, and then get pixel color via mouse position.

Maybe you can give more details on what you want to achieve (maybe you want to avoid using a class)

Comment: +1 @Nebu Create a class which extends Sprite. Have a variable which stores a random colour. Have a drawRectangle method which draws a rectangle using the random colour. create a listener for  the mouse over event addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, mouseOverHandler);, in mouseOverHandler dispatch a custom event with the shapes colour as an argument dispatchEvent(new ShapeOverEvent(ShapeOverEvent.OVER, myColour));, listen for the ShapeOverEvent.OVER in the parent.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the [BitmapData](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html) for your area, and then use the `getPixel` method, which will return the color of that pixel.